# What's the easiest way to make a list of most common words in a list?

Tags: text-processing

Say I have a bunch of textfiles containing fiction, non-fiction, newspaper articles, &c (random examples of text in a given language.)

I want a frequency list of the given words, most common word first.

I could write some C code to do this, but if there's a faster way to do this, I'd like to know it.  (When I say faster, I mean coding time, not run time.)

Comment: This question is pretty close to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41479/find-n-most-frequent-words-in-a-file/41480#41480

Comment: @BruceEdiger: similar but not the same, AFAIUI Korgan wants the frequency of specific words, which doesn't  require any sorting.

Comment: Throw a `tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` into the pipe to consider `This`, `this`, `THIS` and even `ThIs` to be the same word.

Answer (score 4):

For faster coding time, This is what I try successfully right now :

```
printf '%s\n' $(cat *.txt) | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr | less
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, although it counts "This" and "This," as two words.  Any way to fix that?

Comment: @KorganRivera, remove unwanted punctuation before passing it to `printf` with `tr`: `cat *.txt | tr '[:punct:]' ' '`. You may also want to make the match case-insensitive: `tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'`.

Comment: @Thor Thanks.  I want to keep it case-sensitive.  I'm trying to make a list of the most common German words in given texts.  All German nouns are capitalised, so.

Comment: @Korgan Rivera - what you ask for is called "stop words" or a "stop list" See my answer in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41479/find-n-most-frequent-words-in-a-file/41480#41480 for how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Writing it in C will most likely have a fast runtime, but it takes longer to write. A good compromise might be to use awk:

*tally.awk*

```
FNR == NR { pat[$1] = 1; next }
{
  for(p in pat) 
    if(index($0, p)) 
      pat[p]++
} 
END { 
  for(p in pat) 
    print pat[p]-1, p
}
```

This will first read in a word list (one word per line), then count matches found in the rest of the input. Run it like this:

```
cat *.txt | awk -f tally.awk wordlist - | sort -nr
```

The above will match substrings as well, if you only want to match whole words, replace the `index` line with:

```
if(match($0, "\\<" p "\\>"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do (with GNU grep):

```
grep -hEo "[[:alnum:]_'-]+" ./*.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Change `[:alnum:]_'-` above to what should be word constituents.