# How to find the most common name in passwd file

Tags: text-processing, grep, sort

My `/etc/passwd` has a list of users in a format that looks like this:

```
username:password:uid:gid:firstname.lastname, somenumber:/...
```

**Goal :** I want to see only the first names and than sort them having the most common name appear first, 2nd most common appear 2nd etc....

I saw some [solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41479/find-n-most-frequent-words-in-a-file/41480) as to how to do the 2nd part, although they are relevant to working with a text file and not to reading from a map.

In regards to the first part, I really don't know how to approach this. I know that there are some solutions but don't really know how to do them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
cut -d: -f5 /etc/passwd | \
    sed 's/\..*//' | \
    sort -i | \
    uniq -ci | \
    sort -rn
```

Comment: Great answer, but I think he'll be in need of using `uniq` without `-i`, since there should be difference between X and x in name, we only need --ignore-case option for sort as you've used. In addition, using the sed command you've added in your answer, seems irrelevant, if there is any reason, please explain.

Comment: @FarazX Re: `-i`: `John.Doe` should be the same as `john.doe`.  Re: `sed`: from the OP: _I want to see only the first names_.

Comment: Oh you're right, sorry I didn't notice. So voila! Thanks for your explanation, and your great way of using cut ;)

Comment: **cut** + **sed** is too much `sed '/\n/{P;d};s/:/\n/4;s/\./\n/;D'` or `sed 's/[^.]*:\(\w\+\).*/\1/'`

Comment: @Costas Too much compared to what?  For me, total time spent thinking about getting the 5th field portably with `sed` >> the time gained by not using `cut`.  BTW, your second recipe assumes GNU `sed` (`\w`).

Comment: @SatoKatsura The above is example. If you'd like you can do the same as in your script `sed 's/[^.]*://;s/\..*//'`. But my 1st example a little bit quicker. AND if you don't like `\w` you free to use `[:alnum:]`

Comment: @Costas `sed 's/[^.]*://;s/\..*//'` misses any names without dot.  The point of using `cut` is precisely to avoid going into this kind of details, you know.

Comment: @SatoKatsura If you insist `s/\([^:]*:\)\{4\}//;s/[:.].*//` In any way if you involve  *sed* you can easily avoid *cut*

Comment: Can u explain briefly how this command works? (specifically the `sed` and `cut` part)

Comment: And btw, in my system I don't have access to passwd. I have to type `ypcat passwd` to read it.

Comment: @PanthersFan92 `cut` extracts the 5th field, `sed` kills the `.lastname, somenumber` part out of it.  You can, of course, do it like this: `ypcat passwd | cut -d: -f5 | ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk and sorting to have the most common name first:

```
awk -F: '{sub(/[.].*/, "", $5); a[$5]++} END{for (n in a)print a[n],n}' /etc/passwd | sort -nr
```

For a case-insensitive version:

```
awk -F: '{sub(/[. ,].*/, "", $5); a[tolower($5)]++} END{for (n in a)print a[n],n}' /etc/passwd | sort -nr
```

For those who prefer their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
awk -F: '
  {
    sub(/[.].*/, "", $5)
    a[$5]++
  }

  END{
    for (n in a)
      print a[n],n
  }
  ' /etc/passwd | sort -nr
```

#### How it works

- `-F:`

  This makes `:` the field separator.
- `sub(/[.].*/, "", $5)`

  This removes everything after the first period from field 5.
- `a[$5]++`

  The count for the number of times this name has appeared is stored in associative array `a`.  This increments the counter.  For the case-insensitive version, this is replaced with `a[tolower($5)]++`.
- `END{for (n in a)print a[n],n}`

  This prints the count and name for all the results that we have in array `a`.
- `sort -nr`

  This sorts the output numerically in descending order.

Comment: FWIW if GNU awk 4+ you can set `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"` and drop the separate `sort`