# find n most frequent words in a file with a stop words list from the command line

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I want to find the most frequent words in a text file, with using a stop words list. I already have this code:

```
tr -c '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' < test.txt |
fgrep -v -w -f /usr/share/groff/current/eign |
sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head  -10 > test.txt
```

from an old [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41479/find-n-most-frequent-words-in-a-file)
but my file contains something like this:

```
240 
 21 ipsum
 20 Lorem
 11 Textes
 9 Blindtexte
 7 Text
 5 F
 5 Blindtext
 4 Texte
 4 Buchstaben
```

The first one is just a Space and in the text they are punctuation marks (like points), but I don´t want this, so what does I have to add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat text.txt
this file has "many" words, some
with punctuation.  some repeat,
many do not.
```

To get a word count:

```
$ grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+' text.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
      2 some
      2 many
      1 words
      1 with
      1 this
      1 repeat
      1 punctuation
      1 not
      1 has
      1 file
      1 do
```

#### How it works

- `grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+' text.txt`

  This returns all words, minus any spaces or punctuation, with one word per line.
- `sort`

  This sorts the words into alphabetical order.
- `uniq -c`

  This counts the number of times each word occurs.  (For `uniq` to work, its input must be sorted.)
- `sort -nr`

  This sorts the output numerically so that the most frequent word is at the top.

#### Handling mixed case

Consider this mixed-case test file:

```
$ cat Text.txt
This file has "many" words, some
with punctuation.  Some repeat,
many do not.
```

If we want to count `some` and `Some` as the same:

```
$ grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+' Text.txt | sort -f | uniq -ic | sort -nr
      2 some
      2 many
      1 words
      1 with
      1 This
      1 repeat
      1 punctuation
      1 not
      1 has
      1 file
      1 do
```

Here, we added the `-f` option to `sort` so that it would ignore case and the `-i` option to `uniq` so that it also would ignore case.

#### Excluding stop words

Suppose that we want to exclude these stop words from the count:

```
$ cat stopwords 
with
not
has
do
```

So, we add `grep -v` to eliminate these words:

```
$ grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+' Text.txt | grep -vwFf stopwords | sort -f | uniq -ic | sort -nr
      2 some
      2 many
      1 words
      1 This
      1 repeat
      1 punctuation
      1 file
```

Answer (score 1):

**Command:**

```
cat text.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v 'words\|word2' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nk1
```

#### How this works

Following is the file content

$ cat file.txt

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

```
$ cat file.txt|tr ' ' '\n'| grep -v -w 'an\|a\|is'| sort| uniq -c| sort -nk1|tail
      1 unknown
      1 when
      2 and
      2 dummy
      2 Ipsum
      2 Lorem
      2 of
      2 text
      2 type
      3 the
```

**Description** : Translate the space with new line, then excude the words from the list, then sort it and counted for the frequent used one's