# How to make BSD grep respect start-of-line anchor

Tags: grep, osx

I'm trying to match the first character on a line with `grep`, and print only that character.  With GNU grep 2.20 in Linux I do something like this:

```
$ echo ab | grep -o '^.'
a
$
```

This is works as I expect it - the `^` anchors the regexp to the start of the line and only the `a` character is printed.

However with BSD grep 2.5.1 on MacOS I get a different result:

```
$ echo ab | egrep -o '^.'
a
b
$
```

It is as if the `^` start-of-line anchor is being ignored.  Interestingly the `$` end-of-line anchor works as expected on both `grep` flavours:

```
$ echo ab | grep -o '.$'
b
$
```

Interestingly, BSD grep does respect the `^` start-of-line anchor if the `-o` option is not used:

```
$ { echo a ; echo b; } | grep '^a'
a
$
```

- Does BSD grep have some other way to express `^` when `-o` is used?
- Is there a portable way to express `^` when `-o` is used that I can use with both Linux and MacOS?
- Is this a bug in BSD grep?

Comment: `(echo ab; echo cd) | /usr/bin/egrep -o '^.'` on OpenBSD 6.2 gives `a` and then `c` so it's probably at least a macOS bug

Comment: @thrig interesting.  I just tried FreeBSD 11 and your test yields `a\nb\nc\nd\n`.  In that the `grep` version is `2.5.1-FreeBSD`.  What version does OpenBSD have?

Comment: On OpenBSD 5.8, I get `a\nb\nc\nd\n` (as another data point).

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398223/ .

Answer (score 2):

Digging a bit deeper, I found this behavior reported in a [FreeBSD bug](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166842):

> I've noticed some more issues with the same version of grep. I don't
>   know whether they're related, but I'll append them here for now.
>
> $ printf abc | grep -o '^[a-c]'
>
> should just print 'a', but instead gives three hits, against each letter
>   of the incoming text.

But it's not clear to me if or when this will be fixed.

Comment: It seems clear to me that the base system grep on FreeBSD is GNU grep and that there are plans to replace it within a short enough time (a couple of years or so) for them not to bother fixing the bug right now at least.

Comment: The questioner is using MacOS, not FreeBSD, Kusalananda.