# Confusion about difference in GNU/macOS grep output when using -o

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Why does BSD `grep` on macOS produce only the first word here:

```
$ echo "once upon a time" | grep -o "[a-z]*"
once
```

but all words here:

```
$ echo "once upon a time" | grep -o "[a-z][a-z]*"
once
upon
a
time
```

Or, using extended regular expressions:

```
$ echo "once upon a time" | grep -E -o "[a-z]*"
once

$ echo "once upon a time" | grep -E -o "[a-z]+"
once
upon
a
time
```

GNU `grep` will produce identical output for both `[a-z]+` (or `[a-z][a-z]*`) and `[a-z]*`:

```
$ echo "once upon a time" | ggrep -E -o "[a-z]*"
once
upon
a
time

$ echo "once upon a time" | ggrep -E -o "[a-z]+"
once
upon
a
time
```

Comment: Hmm... there seems to be a difference between how BSD `grep` deals with `[a-z]*` and `[a-z][a-z]*` (using BREs here) when `-o` is used. The first will only return the first word, while the second will return each word separately. I'm testing on OpenBSD. GNU `grep` treats both expressions the same ("treats" = "gives identical results", they are quite different expressions).

Comment: Interestingly, adding `-w`, as in `grep -ow '[a-z]*'`, return each word, so it has something to do with the word boundaries.

Comment: Same on FreeBSD. See how `echo " once upon a time" | grep -o "[a-z]*"` returns nothing. I suspect it stops at the first empty match. GNU grep skips all the empty matches and ast-open's grep runs into infinite loops if there are any as it resumes the search for more at the same location in the text.

Comment: Even more strangely, `echo " once upon a time" | grep -o "[a-z]*"` doesn't actually return nothing - it returns a single empty line with macOS `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`. `echo "once upon a time"|grep -o -E '[a-z]*'` returns two matches, "once" *and* an empty line.

Comment: It's as if the FreeBSD grep stopped at the first empty match. (I tested the same ancient grep on Mac.) Which is sort of logical, since if you can find one such, you can usually find many others, and printing them all (with `-o`) would just be silly. Now, someone just needs to go look at the source code to see if it does that on purpose, or by accident...

Comment: My comment above about `-w` refers to OpenBSD `grep` which seems to be different from both FreeBSD and macOS `grep` (which I believe share ancestor). OpenBSD `grep` does not produce empty lines with any of the examples mentioned in comments (by @MichaelHomer) .

Comment: Counter-question: Does a pattern that matches the empty string make any sense with `grep` at all? Without `-o`, such pattern matches each and every input line. With `-o`, should all the empty matches be printed? If empty matches are ignored (like GNU grep does), then a successful `grep -o` can produce an empty output, which is sort of confusing if you think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collecting the thoughts of the comment section, it seems this comes down to how different `grep` implementations have decided to deal with empty matches, and the `[a-z]*` expressions matches on the empty string.

The `-o` option is not defined by POSIX, so how an implementation deals with it is left to the developers.

GNU `grep` obviously throws away empty matches, for example the match of the empty string after `once` when using `[a-z]*`, and continues to process the input from the next character onwards.

BSD `grep`, seems to be hitting the empty match and decides that, for whatever reason, that's enough, and stops there.

Stéphane mentions that the `ast-open` version of `grep` actually goes into an infinite loop at the empty match of `[a-z]*` after `once` and doesn't get past that point in the string.

OpenBSD `grep` seems to be different from macOS and FreeBSD `grep` in that adding the `-w` flag (which requires the matches to be delimited by word boundaries) makes `[a-z]*` return each word separately.

ilkkachu makes the observation that `-o` with a pattern that allows matching an empty string in some sense is confusing (or possibly at least ambiguous). Should all empty matches be printed? There are in fact infinitely many such matches after each word in the given string.

---

The OpenBSD source for `grep` (which exhibit the same behaviour as `grep` on macOS) contains ([`src/usr.bin/grep/util.c`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/grep/util.c?rev=1.58&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)):

```
               if (r == 0) {
                        c = 1;
                        if (oflag && pmatch.rm_so != pmatch.rm_eo)
                                goto print;
                        break;
                }
        }
        if (oflag)
                return c;
print:
```

This basically says, if the pattern matched (`r == 0`) and if we are using `-o` (`oflag`), and if the match start offset is the same as the match end offset (`pmatch.rm_so == pmatch.rm_eo`, i.e. an empty match), then the result of the match is *not* printed and the matching on this particular line of input ends (`return c` with `c == 1` for "match found").

Comment: See how `echo once upon a time | sed 's/[a-z]*/<&>/g'` does it and how an empty match is _not_ found after `once`. In `echo once--upon | sed 's/[a-z]*/<&>/g'` and empty match is found in between the two `-`s. A `grep -o` implementation could choose to behave like `sed` here, but I don't know any that does, though you can implement it as `perl -lne 'print for /pattern/'`

Comment: You might want to look over https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398249/5132 and the associated bug reports, too.

Comment: @JdeBP The [fix commit](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=316477) confirms that a bailout is done on emtpy matches when `-o` is used. This is probably incorporated into macOS `grep` as well (either from FreeBSD or separately).

Comment: Actually `perl -lpe 's/[a-z]*/<$&>/g'` behave differently from `sed 's/[a-z]*/<&>/g'` here and does find an empty match after `once`.

Comment: Also interesting: `echo once upon a time | perl -lne '@_= /[a-z]*(?{print pos()})/g'`

Comment: @JdeBP The bailout for empty matches with `-o`  was implemented in OpenBSD `grep` in 2012: https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/grep/util.c#rev1.44

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Empty match not only after `once`: `<once><> <upon><> <a><> <time><>`.