# Why BSD grep is not returning all the results, but GNU does?

Tags: shell, grep, osx, gnu

Given the file with numbers from 1 to 100 (`seq 1 100 > dataset.txt`),

and the pattern file with numbers from 1 to 20 (`seq 1 20 > patterns.txt`),

I would like to to print all exact matches from the dataset file given the list of patterns.

Here is my command using BSD `grep`:

```
$ \grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

$ \grep -w -F -f patterns.txt dataset.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

but the output is missing the numbers from 10 to 20.

However all patterns are printed when running the same command in GNU `grep`, e.g.

```
$ \ggrep --version
ggrep (GNU grep) 3.1
Packaged by Homebrew

$ \ggrep -w -F -f patterns.txt dataset.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

When tested with [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), all are returned as well.

Why is that? Is there any different approach to make them both return the same result?

Comment: I suspect this is due to the combination of `-w` (which enables regexy bits) and `-F` (which disables regexy bits). I'd either omit `-w` or put the full exact regex into the pattern list file.

Comment: Change `-w` to `-x` and try again.

Comment: Oh look!  It's https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398223/ again.  (-:

Comment: @Kusalananda Using `-x` doesn't changes anything.