# How to get unique occurence of words from a vey large file?

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed, uniq

I have been asked to write a word frequency analysis program using the
unix/ shell-scripts with the following requirements:

- Input is a text file with one word per line
- Input words are    drawn from the Compact Oxford English Dictionary New Edition
- Character encoding is UTF-8
- Input file is 1 Pebibyte (PiB) in    length
- Output is of the format “ Word occurred N times”

I am aware of one of the way to begin with as below ---
cat filename | xargs -n1 | sort | uniq -c > newfilename

What should be the best optimal way to do that considering performance as well?

Comment: have you tried using `uniq` and `sort` commands? also add sample input/output (say 5-10 lines).. title and description is not matching..

Comment: This really sounds like homework. The optimal solution is to to what you did. Ask someone else. The best is to learn how to use of `cat` `xargs` `uniq` and `|`.

Comment: If you look over to the right on this very page, and scroll down a bit, you will find a header "related."  Click on the links there and read them.  You will find what you need to do your homework.  Yes, it will involve learning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find n most frequent words in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41479/find-n-most-frequent-words-in-a-file)

Comment: You cannot use `sort` with a Petabyte of data. You have to split the input data into files /data sets  of reasonable size (which you probably have to determine by trial and error) and add up the results. You need not write smaller files, you can use e.g. `awk` to create a new `sort | uniq -c` pipeline for each data set and save a lot of I/O by that. You can save even more I/O by writing the partial results to tmpfs and adding them up there.

Comment: The COED is about 150K entries (according to Wikipedia), fairly easy to to do with associative arrays, `bash` can likely do it. With 1PiB your main problem is IO, you have to read the file only once (which the associative array allow you to do). Of course you can wonder where they will find the 1PiB file, since this isn't a trivial size...

Comment: @HaukeLaging splitting the file triples the I/O (1 read, one write, one read). Not something you want to do if you have 1PiB of input.

Comment: @xenoid And that's why I explained that splitting the data does not require reading or writing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### **NOTICE:**
>
> This is a paid product, although open source so you could install and run it yourself for free.  However you can get a free trial to test it in our cloud if you like.  I don't necessarily expect you to purchase an account but if you have a need to process data in very large text files, Manta will do exactly that beautifully.
>
> Additionally I work for Joyent, the company that sells the product so take my opinion with a grain of salt but I encourage you to try the product for yourself and let it prove itself.

[Joyent](https://www.joyent.com/)'s object store [Manta](https://www.joyent.com/triton/object-storage) is perfectly suited for working with large data inputs and running compute against them on our systems.

The uses for Manta are [vast](https://apidocs.joyent.com/manta/#some-use-cases) but I'll focus on your question specifically:

### [Running Compute on Data](https://apidocs.joyent.com/manta/index.html#running-compute-on-data)

Upload some datasets:

```
$ curl -sL http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1661.txt.utf-8 | \
    mput -H 'content-type: text/plain' ~~/stor/books/sherlock_holmes.txt
$ curl -sL http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/76.txt.utf-8 | \
    mput -H 'content-type: text/plain' ~~/stor/books/huck_finn.txt
$ curl -sL http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701.txt.utf-8 | \
    mput -H 'content-type: text/plain' ~~/stor/books/moby_dick.txt
$ curl -sL http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/345.txt.utf-8 | \
    mput -H 'content-type: text/plain' ~~/stor/books/dracula.txt
```

---

Running jobs on your data

*Here's an example job that counts the number of times the word "vampire" appears in Dracula.*

```
$ echo ~~/stor/books/dracula.txt | mjob create -o -m "grep -ci vampire"
added 1 input to 7b39e12b-bb87-42a7-8c5f-deb9727fc362
32
```

> this command creates a job to run the user script `grep -ci vampire` on each input object and then submits `~~/stor/books/dracula.txt` as the only input to the job. The name of the job is (in this case) `7b39e12b-bb87-42a7-8c5f-deb9727fc362`. When the job completes, the result is placed in an output object, which you can see with the `mjob outputs` command

---

*You can use a similar invocation to run the same job on all of the objects under* `~~/stor/books`:

```
$ mfind -t o ~~/stor/books | mjob create -o -m "grep -ci human"
added 5 inputs to 69219541-fdab-441f-97f3-3317ef2c48c0
13
48
18
4
6
```

> In this example, the system runs 5 invocations of `grep`. Each of these is called a task. Each task produces one output, and the job itself winds up with 5 separate outputs.

---

### [Map and Reduce Phases](https://apidocs.joyent.com/manta/index.html#multiple-phases-and-reduce-tasks)

> We've just described the "map" phase of traditional map-reduce computations. The "map" phase performs the same computation on each of the input objects. The reduce phase typically combines the outputs from the map phase to produce a single output.

---

*One of the earlier examples computed the number of times the word "human" appeared in each book. We can use a simple `awk` script in the reduce phase to get the total number the of times "human" appears in all the books.*

```
$ mfind -t o ~~/stor/books | \
        mjob create -o -m "grep -ci human" -r "awk '{s+=\$1} END{print s}'"
added 5 inputs to 12edb303-e481-4a39-b1c0-97d893ce0927
89
```

> This job has two phases: the map phase runs `grep -ci human` on each input object, then the reduce phase runs the `awk` script on the concatenated output from the first phase. `awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'` sums a list of numbers, so it sums the list of numbers that come out of the first phase. You can combine several map and reduce phases. The outputs of any non-final phases become inputs for the next phase, and the outputs of the final phase become job outputs.

---

I'm not quite sure what you are looking for exactly but this is closer to the command in your question:

```
echo ~~/stor/books/dracula.txt | mjob create -o -m "cat" -r "tr -s '[:blank:]' '[\n*]'" -r "sort" -r "uniq -c" >./tmp/test.txt
```

**Output**

```
   2559
      1 "'Are
      1 "'E's
      1 "'I
      1 "'Ittin'
      1 "'Little
      1 "'Lucy,
      1 "'Maybe
      1 "'Miss
      2 "'My
      1 "'Never
      1 "'No'
      1 "'Ow
      1 "'Silence!
      1 "'That's
      1 "'Tyke
      1 "'Wilhelmina'--I
      1 "'Yes,
      8 "A
      ...
```